# How to make rangeSelector do dataGrouping of multiple series

Tags: highcharts

If you group by day only the first series is grouped. How can I make it so it groups both series?

In the above example, both series have the same data, but my current situation consists of two series with the same x value in every point but different y values.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6751x0yj/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector : {
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: 'Day',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['day', [1]]]
                }
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: 'Week',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['week', [1]]]
                }
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'Month',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [['month', [1]]]
                }
            }],
            buttonTheme: {
                width: 60
            },
            selected: 2
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Custom data grouping tied to range selector'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'Series 1',
            data : data,
            marker: {
                enabled: null, // auto
                radius: 3,
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },{
            name : 'Series 2',
            data : data,
            marker: {
                enabled: null, // auto
                radius: 3,
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug, which you already reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4335).

Workaround is to update series in descending order:

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, "setDataGrouping", function (p, dg, r) {
    if (!dg) {
        dg = {
            forced: false,
            units: null
        };
    }

    if (this instanceof H.Axis) {
        for(var i = this.series.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            this.series[i].update({
                dataGrouping: dg
            }, false);
        };
    }

    p.call(this, dg, r);
});
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6751x0yj/2/

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks a lot. Another question: Seems like data grouping is lost when the xAxis extremes are updated. How can I keep the current data grouping after the extremes are updated? Thanks

Comment: It depends, if you change range, then dataGrouping will change. If you change just the position of the navigator, dataGrouping shouldn't change. I think it would be easier to create your own buttons, which will just update series with required dataGrouping.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks a lot!